# no compilation errors when calling this.method inside callback

Tags: angular, typescript, tslint

durring refactoring I encountered problem with no compilation errors when calling method using `this` binding in callback function

sample (simplified) code:

```
private test(flag:boolean){
  console.log(flag)
}

private subscribeWithoutError() {
  this.websocket.createSubscription('/topic/test', function (message) {
    this.test("abc"); //no compilation error
  }.bind(this));
}

private subscribeWithError() {
  let that = this;
  this.websocket.createSubscription('/topic/test', function (message) {
    that.test("abc"); //compilation error that string is not assignable to boolean
  });
}
```

durring compilation of this code (or viewing in intelij) `subscribeWithoutError` has no errors, despite inteliJ showing that signature with boolean parameter

`subscribeWithError` uses `that` and has compilation error as expected

im using typescript 4.1.2
is there any way to tweek compilator/this code to report compilation errors in example with binding and calling `this`, I have multiple similar subscriptions and I would want to know that code has compilation problems durring refactoring, currently problem only apears during runtime :/

Comment: I'd suggest using arrow functions for the callback. That way, you're on the safe side when accessing `this`.

Comment: Well, using `this` inside a callback is not a compilation error. Synthactically it's totally ok, but semantically it's not (different context). This would be a case for linting I guess (either saying to always use arrow functions or to bind `this`).

Comment: I refactored code to use arrow function, and it solved problem